# Returning a reference to a captured mutable variable

Tags: rust

So I have a function which looks like this

```rust
fn foo() {
    let items = vec![0.2, 1.5, 0.22, 0.8, 0.7, 2.1];
    let mut groups: HashMap<u32, String> = HashMap::new();

    let mut group = |idx: f32| -> &mut String {
        let rounded = (idx / 0.2).floor() as u32;
        groups
            .entry(rounded)
            .or_insert_with(|| format!("{}:", rounded))
    };

    for item in items.iter() {
        group(*item).push_str(&format!(" {}", item))
    }
}
```

and this code does not compile, with the following error:

```rust
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/main.rs:9:9
   |
5  |       let mut groups: HashMap<u32, String> = HashMap::new();
   |           ---------- variable defined here
6  | 
7  |       let mut group = |idx: f32| -> &mut String {
   |                                     - inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
8  |           let rounded = (idx / 0.2).floor() as u32;
9  |           groups
   |           ^-----
   |           |
   |  _________variable captured here
   | |
10 | |             .entry(rounded)
11 | |             .or_insert_with(|| format!("{}:", rounded))
   | |_______________________________________________________^ returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

*Edit*

As [@Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach) pointed out, the problem here is that I could create 2 mutable references to the same object:

```
fn foo() {
    // ...    
    let ok = groups(0.1);
    let problem = groups(0.1);
}
```

*Original (incorrect)*

> I think that Rust is telling me, the closure `group` is mutably capturing the variable `groups` and then returning a reference to an object owned by `groups`. So the danger here is that the following code would return a dangling pointer (since `groups` is dropped when it goes out of scope after `foo` finishes).
>
> ```
> fn foo() -> &String {
>         /* ... */ return groups(0.1); }
> ```

So is there any way to return a reference from a captured mutable `HashMap` like this?

Comment: The problem is not that you might return the reference from `foo()`. The problem is that you could call `group()` a second time and end up with two mutable references to the same value. It's just as the error message states – an `FnMut` closure can't return a reference to any of its captured values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think that Rust is telling me, the closure group is mutably capturing the variable groups and then returning a reference to an object owned by groups. So the danger here is that if I were to write:
>
> then I would be returning a dangling pointer (since groups is dropped when it goes out of scope after foo finishes).

No. If that were the case Rust could (and would) warn about *that*.

The problem is that the lifetimes around function traits are problematic, because they don't have a way to match the lifetime of the result to the lifetime of *the function itself*.

As a result, rust blanket bans returning [any reference to captured data](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b269a20825075615a354209bf53bd94) from a closure.

As far as I can tell the solutions are:

1. don't use a closure, instead pass in `groups` as an argument into the function (anonymous or named)
2. use some sort of shared ownership and interior mutability e.g. have the map store and return `Rc<RefCell<String>>`
3. desugar the closure to a structure with a method, that way the lifetimes become manageable:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct F<'a>(&'a mut HashMap<u32, String>);

impl F<'_> {
    fn call(&mut self, idx: f32) -> &mut String {
        let rounded = (idx / 0.2).floor() as u32;
        self.0
            .entry(rounded)
            .or_insert_with(|| format!("{}:", rounded))
    }
}

pub fn foo() {
    let items = vec![0.2, 1.5, 0.22, 0.8, 0.7, 2.1];
    let mut groups: HashMap<u32, String> = HashMap::new();

    let mut group = F(&mut groups);

    for item in items.iter() {
        group.call(*item).push_str(&format!(" {}", item))
    }
}
```

Note that the above stores a reference to match the original closure, but in reality I see no reason not to move the hashmap into the wrapper entirely (and the struct can init itself fully without the need for a two-step initialisation as well):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct F(HashMap<u32, String>);

impl F {
    fn new() -> Self { Self(HashMap::new()) }
    fn call(&mut self, idx: f32) -> &mut String {
        let rounded = (idx / 0.2).floor() as u32;
        self.0
            .entry(rounded)
            .or_insert_with(|| format!("{}:", rounded))
    }
}

pub fn foo() {
    let items = vec![0.2, 1.5, 0.22, 0.8, 0.7, 2.1];

    let mut group = F::new();

    for item in items.iter() {
        group.call(*item).push_str(&format!(" {}", item))
    }
}
```